# Key not authorized to access app

Tags: heroku, ssh

I went through the tutorial in here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python and then I changed the remote address of git to the one in one of the apps in my dashboard in Heroku. But then after, when I try to push to master, I get

```
git push heroku master

 !  Your key with fingerprint 55:55:55:55:55:55 is not authorized to access damp-garden-2012.

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I tried `ssh-add -d` and that didn't work

edit: when i do `ssh-add -D` and then `ssh-add -l` I still get:

```
2048 33:33:33:33:33:33:33 one@email.com (RSA)
2048 44:44:44:44:44:44:44 different@email.com (RSA)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check what keys Heroku has via `heroku keys`, to add a new key use `heroku keys:add`. More info on managing keys can be found at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys